# mockito when thenReturn does not return stubbed array list

Tags: junit, mockito

```java
List<Populate> fullAttrPopulateList = getFullAtrributesPopulateList(); //Prepare return list

when(mockEmployeeDao.getPopulateList(null)).thenReturn(fullAttrPopulateList);

MyDTO myDto = testablePopService.getMyPopData(); //Will call mockEmployeeDao.getPopulateList(null)

//verify(mockEmployeeDao,times(1)).getPopulateList(null);

assertEquals(fullAttrPopulateList.size(), myDto.getPopData().size()); //This fails because myDto.getPopData().size() returns 0
```

As you can see `testablePopService.getMyPopData()` calls `mockEmployeeDao.getPopulateList(null)` but when I debug it a zero sized list returns instead of the stubbed array list which is prepared by `getFullAtrributesPopulateList();`
If I uncomment the verify statement, it passes the test meaning `getPopulateList(null)` behavior does get called.
Can anyone give me some advice why my stubbed array list cannot be returned even it is verified the expected behavior happened? How come an empty array list returns rather than a null if I did something wrong?

Comment: There can be lots of reasons, so it's not possible to give you an answer telling you authoritatively why.  (1) Maybe `getMyPopData` doesn't do what you think it does.  (2) Maybe `getPopulateList` is final or private, in which case it can't be stubbed.  (3) Maybe your `EmployeeDao` class is private.  But without seeing more of your code, all anyone can do is guess.

Answer (score 0):

First, check that the method is non-`final` and visible throughout its hierarchy. Mockito can have trouble mocking methods that are hidden (e.g. overriding a package-private abstract class's implementation); also, Mockito is [entirely unable to mock `final` methods](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/FAQ#What_are_the_limitations_of_Mockito), or even to detect that the method is `final` and warn you about it.

You may also want to check that your call is using the overload you expect. Mockito's default list return value is an empty list, so you may simply stubbing one method and seeing the default value for another. You can see which method interactions Mockito has added by adding a call to `verifyZeroInteractions` temporarily, and Mockito will throw an exception with a list of calls that mock has received. You could also add `verifyNoMoreInteractions`, and even leave it in there, at the expense of test brittleness (i.e. the test breaks when the actual code continues to work).